# Split map reduce method single item error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a split.map.reduce method that calculates an average number. It works fine if there are more than two numbers. I would like this method to be used only when there are two or more values.

Example: 8,6,10 | AVG = 8,00 (works OK)

Example 2: 9 | AVG = 9 (it gives me an error if there is only one value)

This is my method:

```js
grade.grade.split(',')
  .map(v => Number(v))
  .reduce((a, c, i, arr) => {a += c; if (i === arr.length - 1) { a /= arr.length } return a}, 0)
  .toFixed(2)
```

```js
const grade = { grade: '9' }

const avg = grade.grade.split(',')
  .map(v => Number(v))
  .reduce((a, c, i, arr) => { a += c; if (i === arr.length - 1) { a /= arr.length } return a }, 0)
  .toFixed(2);

console.log(avg);
```

I'm using this in JSX

Full JSX table code:

```
table className="table__date">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Materia</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>AVG</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {studentsGrades
            .filter((a) => Number(a.partial) === Number(semester))
            .map((grade, i) => {
              return (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td className="alignRight">
                    <span>{getSubjectName(grade.userSubject)}</span>
                  </td>
                  <td>{grade.grade}</td>
                  <td>{ 
                      grade.grade.split(',').map(v => Number(v)).reduce((a, c, i, arr) => {a += c; if (i === arr.length - 1) { a /= arr.length } return a}, 0).toFixed(2)
                  }
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: works fine for me. but you don't need the `map()` you can just `a += +c;` and using index as key is only going to cause you problems later, use a unique value of grade

Comment: Are you saying you **want** it to throw an error, or it **does** throw an error and you don't know why?

Comment: it throws an error if there is only one element. I want to modify my method so it would work even when there is only one value

Comment: What might that error be?

Comment: TypeError: grade.grade.split is not a function

Comment: That seems to be a type error, is it a number when its only a single value, instead of a string? `{grade: 9}` vs `{grade: '9'}`

Comment: i guess thats the problem

Comment: Could i add some kind of validation - if there are 2 or more values then do this method, but if there is only one value, then avg = value

Comment: It would be better to have consistently typed data, but yes you can type check the property before splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that single value grades are entered as numbers, while multiple grades are strings. Numbers don't implement a `split()` method so are throwing an error.

It would be best to rectify the data source so that it is consistently typed, but if you can't you can type check the value before proceeding.

```
<td>
  {
    typeof grade.grade === 'number'
      ? grade.grade
      : grade.grade.split(',')
        .map(v => Number(v))
        .reduce((a, c, i, arr) => { a += c; if (i === arr.length - 1) { a /= arr.length } return a }, 0)
        .toFixed(2)
  }
</td>
```

Comment: This works just fine. Thank you. I was retrieving grades as numbers from database, so that was the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the edge case where there is only 1 data.

```js
var grade={
  grade:'9'
}
var grade2={
  grade:'1,2,3'
}
let data1 = grade.grade.split(',');
let data2 = grade2.grade.split(',');

let getAvg = (data)=>{
 return data.length>1?data
  .map(v => Number(v))
  .reduce((a, c, i, arr) => {a += c; if (i === arr.length - 1) { a /= arr.length } return a}, 0)
  .toFixed(2):data[0];
}


console.log(getAvg(data1));

console.log(getAvg(data2));
```

Comment: This solution will have already thrown an error on the `split()` call

Comment: Try it now, this is the issue the OP is facing, if you'd read all the comments.

Comment: @pilchard, dude he cannot send multiple number without it having as string.

Comment: exactly. multiple grades are strings, and single values are numbers, so the split() is failing on single values.

Comment: oh, okay, then he will have to check the type